# Define setContentView with variable

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie in android, and i'm trying to receive a variable through the Intent function, and according the and depending on the value of the variable is supposed to show a contentview.

```
Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
String type = parametros.getString("tipo");
int accao = parametros.getInt("accao");

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (type=="medicamentos") {
        Button voltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        voltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent medIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Listar.class);
                startActivityForResult(medIntent, 0);
            }
        });
        if (accao==1)
            setContentView(R.layout.adicionar_medicamentos);

        if (accao==2)
            setContentView(R.layout.editar_medicamentos);
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `type=="medicamentos"` should be `"medicamentos".equals (type)`

Comment: The getIntent call should go inside onCreate.

Comment: or `type.equals("medicamentos")`

Comment: @Abu but if `type` is `null`, an NPE will be thrown.

Comment: @A--C yes you are right

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do like `Button voltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);` before `setContentView`.

Comment: You should be *incredibly* careful doing this. There might be a legitimate reason to do what you're doing but in most cases it's a design error and is going to cause you major headaches down the road. If the layouts don't contain the same views, you're going to have to check against that value every time before doing a findViewById().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

String type = getIntent().getString("tipo");
int accao = getIntent().getInt("accao");

if (type != null && type.equals("medicamentos")) {
    Button voltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    voltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent medIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Listar.class);
            startActivityForResult(medIntent, 0);
        }
    });
    if (accao==1)
        setContentView(R.layout.adicionar_medicamentos);

    if (accao==2)
        setContentView(R.layout.editar_medicamentos);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` to compare the string.

`==` compares the Object references not their content.

```
if(type.equals("medicamentos")) {
  ....
}
```